# How can I search a table faster?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to search a table for specific a specific value using Ruby and Selenium-webdriver.  I have a method that works but takes a lot of time for some reason.  It is a one row table and the page HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="permitGridContainer">
  <table id="calendar" class="items" style="width:430px;" name="calendar">
    <thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="avail1" class="status r slct" onmouseout="return nd();" onmouseover="return overlib("Available Quota<br>River Launches : 0 of 4");">
            <div class="permitStatus">R</div>
          </td>
          <td id="avail2" class="status r" onmouseout="return nd();" onmouseover="return overlib("Available Quota<br>River Launches : 0 of 4");">
            <div class="permitStatus">R</div>
          </td>
          <td id="avail3" class="status a" onmouseout="return nd();" onmouseover="return overlib("Available Quota<br>River Launches : 89 of 99");">
            <a onclick="javascript:setNewArrivalDate("Sun Sep 06 2015", 2);return false;" href="#">
              A
              <br>
              <small>89</small>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td id="avail4" class="status a" onmouseout="return nd();" onmouseover="return overlib("Available Quota<br>River Launches : 97 of 99");">
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

... I shortened the table it has 14 columns.

I am looking for a column that has an Item available and I am checking the class for this, but the text also changes so there are other things I could look for.

This is the code I am using, but it visibly slow.  I used puts statements to see the progress.  My sense is that is has to do with time accessing the element.  So I was hoping there is a better way to process the table quickly. Thank you.

```
for j in 1..days_to_check[i]
  check_avail = driver.find_element(id: "avail#{j}")
  check_availclass = check_avail.attribute ("class")

  if check_availclass == "status a" or check_availclass == "status a slct" 
    #process if
  end
```

Comment: Can you please explain *I am looking for a column that has an Item available and I am checking the class for this,* and how do you know what row you are looking for?

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem, but at the very least it would be cleaner to just use a CSS selector to check if a matching element exists: `find_element(:css, "#avail#{j}.status.a")` (this will raise a `NoSuchElementError` if, er, no such element exists; if you'd rather it return an empty array use `find_elements` instead).

Comment: Wow thanks for such a quick reply.  I am very new to programming and this site. So I appreciate the patience.

Comment: I am looking for a row that has either class "status a" or an "A" as the value or I can find a number greater than 1 between the <small> <small>  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your comment I would suggest to use the following `xpath`. I find this is often easier and feasible to use better `xpath` than looping though the `html` table

```
//td[(@class='status a') or (@class='status A')]
```

This `xpath` finds the class with `status a` or `status A`

Comment: Thanks, I used the first suggestion and yours looks like it works as well.  I will try it out to see.  The first suggestion seems to find it fast and then I just handled the error. Which seems an odd solution to me, but it works.

Comment: next problem is then need to either calculate a date from the the element, which I have found a work around to do, but I would rather be able to click on the element to run the associated Java script.  Unfortunately, even though I have used the various formats for mouse clicks and get no errors, I also don't get the element to accept a click.  Thanks

Comment: are you saying even you find the element it does not accept click?

Comment: Yes.  I tried all the following  '  driver.find_element(:css, ".status.a").click
  xx = driver.find_element(:css, ".status.a")
  driver.action.move_to(xx).click
  driver.action.move_to(xx).double_click
  driver.action.click(xx).perform
  xx.click'

Comment: '  driver.find_element(:css, ".status.a").click
  xx = driver.find_element(:css, ".status.a")
  driver.action.move_to(xx).click
  driver.action.move_to(xx).double_click
  driver.action.click(xx).perform
  xx.click'

Comment: yes it did not accept the click even though it found the element and I was able to get the id from it and then parse the id to get a number which I added to a start date which gave me an answer I could plug into an input element.  I spent several hours with it and did not get errors just didn't do anything.  However, I tried it again tonight an now it works. At least two of the methods that did not work yesterday.  Go figure?

Comment: What exception it gives you?

Comment: It gave no exceptions.  I just did not perform the click or mouse over.

Comment: The following now works.  'driver.find_element(:css, ".status a").click

Comment: Hmm interesting. Glad you got the solution

Comment: Also 'xx = driver.find_element(:css, ".status a")  xx.click'  works now.    Not sure why it did not work before.   I was able to get the correct attributes, such as "id" from xx.  So not sure why .click did not work.